# Can we give attribute "name" to HTML <table>?

Tags: javascript, html

For the `<form>`, we can use a "name" like `<form name="name">`.

In the same way, can we add it to `<table name="table1">`?

Answer (score 11):

`name` is not an allowed attribute of `<table>` in HTML5. From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html):

> **Permitted attributes**
>
> *global attributes* & *border*

And if you look at the [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html) you won't find `name` in the list.

So you can't put a `name` attribute on a `<table>` and still have valid HTML. [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) however is a global attribute so you can use that instead of `name` (if of course your name is going to be unique within the page).

Try running this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>t</title></head>
<body>
    <table name="pancakes"></table>
</body>
```

through http://validator.w3.org and you'll see that it doesn't like a `name` on `<table>`.

If you're still writing HTML4, you still can't put a `name` attribute on a `<table>`. From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1):

```
<!ATTLIST TABLE                        -- table element --
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  summary     %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- purpose/structure for speech output--
  width       %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- table width --
  border      %Pixels;       #IMPLIED  -- controls frame width around table --
  frame       %TFrame;       #IMPLIED  -- which parts of frame to render --
  rules       %TRules;       #IMPLIED  -- rulings between rows and cols --
  cellspacing %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- spacing between cells --
  cellpadding %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- spacing within cells --
  >
```

There's no `name` in that list and no name in [`coreattrs`, `i18n`, or `events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs) either.

Comment: @user1061038: Pro-tip: the easiest way to figure out these things to to google for "site:w3.org html5" and the element you're interested in; the "site:w3.org" part is important, including that should lead you straight to the relevant section of the specification.

Answer (score 4):

name is not allowed to table, instead of the this you can declare it in `html5` trend

```
<table data-name="my_table"></table>
```

and use it in jquery for instance like that:

```
$('table [data-name=my_table]');
```

Answer (score 0):

No dude, you cannot assign name to the table element.

For the table, you can give an id or a class attribute that refers a particular table in your HTML code and then based on it, you can then make changes to your table via CSS , javascript, jquery etc.

Hope this information helps.. !

Answer (score -3):

`name` is a **standard attribute*, and it can be placed on any element.

However, note that accessing elements by `name` is deprecated in favour of things like `id` and `class`. `name` should be reserved for form elements such as `<input>`.

Comment: No you can't. `<table name="x">` is not valid HTML5 or HTML4.

Answer (score -6):

Yes you can.
e.g.

```
<table name="test" id="test">
<tr>
<td>..Your stuff..</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd: That's the sort of thinking that has left many companies stuck using IE6 because their mission critical apps did things that "worked" despite what the specs said. Paying attention to specifications is important for interoperability and future proofing, you should stick the specs whenever possible and be fully aware of places where you're violating the specs.

Comment: @RashmiNagaraja As pointed out already, please pay attention to the spec rather than the behavior of any given browser.