# request POST not working with <TABLE>

Tags: django, post

With Django 1.8 template, tried to POST table data. I set `<TABLE> id = 'tasktable'`. But in request information, there's no data of 'tasktable'

Also, how can I access dynamic table POST data in Django views?
Is only ways to make id each row?
(like `<td><input id='1_data'></td><td><input id='2_data'></td>`

[POST request info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQH3k.png)

Below Code is template.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#btn-add-row').click( function() {
        $('#tasktable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select name="format"><option value="INT">INT</option><option value="TEXT">TEXT</option></select></td></tr>');
    });
    $('#btn-delete-row').click( function() {
        $('#tasktable > tbody:last > tr:last').remove();
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
Angel Feeder - Manager
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <form class="" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ taskform }}
        <br>
        <button id="btn-add-row" type="button">+</button><button id="btn-delete-row" type="button">-</button>
        <table name='tasktable' id='tasktable' class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data name</th>
                    <th>Format</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><select name="format"><option value="INT">INT</option><option value="TEXT">TEXT</option></select></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">set task</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only form elements with a `name` attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

`name` is not an allowed attribute of `<table>` in HTML5
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677670/3033586

Obviously you have to set unique `name`s for each form element inside `table>tr>td` so you can reference it after `post`

If you want simple styled [model]forms (for example with bootstrap) - look at http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/